# Is elementary OS really free?

Tags: download

I mean, as soon as I enter on the website, it asks me to pay before the downloading. So, is the system  really free? Especially for use in a commercial environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not clearly stated anywhere, elementary OS is free to use in a commercial environment. Tell your legal department it's free to use because it's not explicitly forbidden (on the legal principle that if something is not forbidden, it's permitted).

Answer (score 5):

You can fill in 0,-, that way you could download it for free (gratis).

Related to this, free software isn't always without costs (gratis). Free usually revers to freedom. More on this: https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source

Also see:

- [How can I (re-)download without paying (again)?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-re-download-without-paying-again)
- https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3517/3892

Comment: I see, at least I now know how to download. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, most people confuse that free as in not paying for a beer and drinking it.  But the truth is that someone has to pay for it, if not a friend, yourself or the owner someone most.  The software is free as in freedom to see what is inside and to own it ( not counting the trademarks and logos).

Like the user above said, put a $0 and download the software, if you cannot afford to pay for it.  But the truth is, that everyone can afford at least a dollar.

I am getting use to paying for Apps that I like in the store.  At least a dollar or two.  Again, if you are a student from elementary or high school and cannot afford an ATM card, yeah this is made for you.  Enjoy, if not, give them a buck or two.

PS, I don't work for the team nor do I benefit from your purchase on any shape or form.  I just believe that fair is fair

Comment: Well, I'd like to agree, but right now I care more about practical aspect. How legal it's. Anyway, thanks for the answer.